# Yii one actionIndex() for 4 table from DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql, activerecord, yii

I have 4 tables on my DB, where each table contain (id, name) columns.

Models:

Table1 = id, name;
Table2 = id, name;

I want to do 1 actionIndex() and 1 view file for each table in my GeneralController, but i don't know how do it.

```
public function actionIndex() {
     $model = Table1::model()->findAll();
     $this->render('index', array('model'=>$model);
}
```

Maybe send params in actionIndex($id) for define tables and call function

```
if($id==1) {}
```

But maybe i will have 10-15 tables too with (id, columns)

Answer (score 1):

you can pass several variables to the view:

```
public function actionIndex() {
    $model = Table1::model()->findAll();
    $model2 = Table2::model()->findAll();
    $this->render('index', array('model'=>$model,'model2'=>$model2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do this in this case

```
public function actionIndex($name)
 {
$name=ucfirst(strtolower(rtrim(trim(strip_tags($name)))));
$allTables=array('Table1','Table2','Table3');
if(in_array($name,$allTables))
{
$model = $name::model()->findAll();
$this->render('index', array('model'=>$model);
}
else
{
//render any default view incase if the $name does not belong to any table
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can include models as much as you want this way.

```
public function actionIndex() {
    $model1 = Table1::model()->findAll();
    $model2 = Table2::model()->findAll();
    $model3 = Table3::model()->findAll();

    $params = array('model1'=>$model1,'model2'=>$model2, 'model3'=>$model3);
    $this->render('index', $params);
}
```